# Why performing ANOVA?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons

I have a general question regarding ANOVA. I understand ANOVA can identify statistically different means accross 3 groups (or more).

The assumptions of ANOVA (Homogeneity of variance and normality) are not always verified. For instance, those data violate ANOVA assumptions to some extend:

[image]

[image]

But then, is this really a problem ? I can still perform multiple pairwise-comparisons using non-parametric tests and then compute False discovery rates (FDR) (to prevent loss of statistical power).

Or am I missing something ?

EDIT:

Here are all possible wilcox.test performed (for 6 experiments, there are 15 tests to perform). Shown are p-values and FDR.

Exp_1 Exp_2 Naive p value       FDR

```
1     2   0.266107673 0.4435128

1     3   0.031191163 0.1169669

1     4   0.067982339 0.1699558

1     5   0.086282542 0.1848912

1     6   0.106806361 0.2002619

2     3   0.008295626 0.1105422

2     4   0.018510901 0.1105422

2     5   0.053030303 0.1590909

2     6   0.022108439 0.1105422

3     4   0.863266764 0.9249287

3     5   1.000000000 1.0000000

3     6   0.346999212 0.5204988

4     5   0.812525710 0.9249287

4     6   0.456150660 0.5701883

5     6   0.384456617 0.5242590
```

Comment: Sure, the classical ANOVA might be inappropriate for that particular data. What do you mean about computing the false discovery rate to prevent a loss of statistical power, however?

Comment: In that case, I was thinking of performing  multiple Wilcoxon tests, calculate 'naive' p-values and then calculate False Discovery Rates (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate). I mean that FDR has larger statistical power than a 'simple' bonferroni' corrections.

Comment: (1) If inequality of variances is of concern then use `oneway.test` in R which does not assume equal variances. If null hypothesis is rejected, _ad hoc_ tests can be Welch 2-sample t tests. QQ plot of resids seems norm. (2) It is probably unnecessary to do all ${6\choose 2} = 15$ comparisons _ad hoc._ Put them in order of incr. gp means (maybe 2,1,6,4,5,3). If Gp1 signif diff from Gp 6 then it will also be signif diff from Gp 3 (assuming equal variances and sample sizes). Cutting down on nr of comparisons increases levels of tests and hence gives greater power for each of fewer _ad hoc_ tests.